# How do I access a Navigator or other web-based resources in web_sys?

Tags: rust, webassembly

Recently I read the documentation of Rust and now I decided to play around with the web_sys API. I'm trying to use the `Navigator::do_not_track` getter... well, to be more specific I would like to print the returning value. According to the documentation, that's the signature of the getter:

```
pub fn do_not_track(&self) -> String
```

If I understand this correctly, I should be able to use the `format!` macro:

```
format!("{}", Navigator::do_not_track);
```

I have correctly imported the Navigator API, without any doubt. The error is:

```
error[E0277]: `for<'r> fn(&'r web_sys::features::gen_Navigator::Navigator) -> std::string::String {web_sys::features::gen_Navigator::Navigator::do_not_track}` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  --> src/lib.rs:19:19
   |
19 |     format!("{}", Navigator::do_not_track);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `for<'r> fn(&'r web_sys::features::gen_Navigator::Navigator) -> std::string::String {web_sys::features::gen_Navigator::Navigator::do_not_track}` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `for<'r> fn(&'r web_sys::features::gen_Navigator::Navigator) -> std::string::String {web_sys::features::gen_Navigator::Navigator::do_not_track}`
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
   = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

And if I try to use `web_sys::navigator`, I get

```
could not find "navigator" in "web_sys"
```

How do I access the web navigator API using `web_sys`?

Comment: [`do_not_track`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/0.3.45/web_sys/struct.Navigator.html#method.do_not_track) is an associated function. It needs to be called in order to obtain the string value: `Navigator::do_not_track()`.

Comment: Hm... in this case another error: `expected 1 argument`

Comment: Ah, right, it's a method. The global navigator should be in `web_sys::navigator`, so it's `web_sys::navigator.do_not_track()`.

Comment: If we reference the whole path, it should be `web_sys::Navigator::do_not_track()`, and yet, the same problem: `expected 1 argument`

Comment: and if we try to use `navigator`: `could not find "navigator" in "web_sys"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `Navigator::do_not_track` is a method, which means that a value of type `Navigator` needs to be retrieved first. One possible source of confusion was in not finding how to create it.

Most of the Web resources that you would find as global variables in a DOM-enabled JavaScript environment are available through the `Window` resource. You need to:

1. Ensure that the intended resource is active by enabling the corresponding Cargo feature:

```
web_sys = { version = "0.3", features = ["Navigator, Window"] }
```

2. Retrieve the global window via [`web_sys::window`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/0.3.45/web_sys/fn.window.html), checking that it is available.
3. You can finally retrieve the intended resource through one of the available getter methods ([`window.navigator()`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/0.3.45/web_sys/struct.Window.html#method.navigator)).

The code:

```rust
let window = web_sys::window().expect("Missing Window");

let navigator = window.navigator();

let do_not_track = navigator.do_not_track();
```

See also:

- The [`wasm-bindgen` guide](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/), which also includes guidance on using `web-sys`.

Comment: I have no idea how you found this, the doc is not very friendly

Comment: The documentation is more of a reference than a user guide. I suppose you would be interested in a link to the wasm-bindgen guide, so I left a link in the answer.